# How to Increase Width of Literal control Asp .net

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, .net

I stored & retrieved pdf in database and to show this i use Literal control

**.aspx code**

```
 <div >
    <asp:Literal ID="ltEmbed" runat="server" />
</div>
```

**.cs code**

```
ltEmbed.Text = string.Format(embed, ResolveUrl("~/FileCS.ashx?Id="), id);
```

**Output**

[image]

**Problem Statement**

I want to increase **width of Literal control** like Full screen.

I tried

```
<div style="width:2000px;" >
```

but it is not working to show pdf full size.

Comment: What API you are using to generate pdf?

Comment: I am not generate that pdf i just store it to sql database and retrive from it. and showing using literal control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `asp:Content` control instead of `asp:Literal`.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
     <object data="URL OF YOUR ASPX PAGE THAT GENERATES THE PDF" type="application/pdf"></object>
</asp:Content>
```

Check this link : http://www.nullskull.com/q/10291781/how-to-open-pdf-in-specific-div-tag-on-webform.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I got answer I use this in  **.cs code**

```
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
    string embed = "<object data=\"{0}{1}\" type=\"application/pdf\" width=\"100%\" height=\"600px\">";
    embed += "If you are unable to view file, you can download from <a href = \"{0}{1}&download=1\">here</a>";
    embed += " or download <a target = \"_blank\" href = \"http://get.adobe.com/reader/\">Adobe PDF Reader</a> to view the file.";
    embed += "</object>";
    ltEmbed.Text = string.Format(embed, ResolveUrl("~/FileCS.ashx?Id="), id);
```

Answer (score 0):

A literal will "become" whatever you render inside it as its text... I don't think it has a specific size, unless it renders as a div itself...

If it renders as a div,try width = 100% as a style on the literal control.

If not, try width = 100% on the div

Comment: I appreciate your answer but it increase background size not control showing pdf

Comment: Show us some rendered html?